# Rows are disappearing from Processing screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am using Processing screen to set selected row status. I am using **PXFilteredProcessingJoin** and PXFilter, My primaryview is PXFilter.

My processing filter delegate is singleton, It show processing screen but after closing processing grid show only processed records, i have to force refresh to show all records as per my filter, what am i missing to show all records?

```
/// Constructor
 public OrderStatusChangeProcess() {
            OrderSampling.SetSelected<RecOrder.selected>();
            OrderSampling.SetProcessDelegate(processOrder);           
        }


    public static void processOrder(List<RecOrder> listProcessOrder) {
        //here set variable for global error message.
        var globalError = false;
        //here I have a variable for the po orderNbr nbr to tie to the lines
        var orderNbr = string.Empty;
        //here I create the graph that will do the processing, can be custom graph also
        OrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<OrderEntry>();
        //now cycle through the list of records and process each.
        foreach(var order in listProcessOrder) {
            //here I have a local variable for each line
            var lineError = false;
            //it is also possible to add transaction support here if only needed for the line item
            try {
                graph.Clear();
                //assign the new receipt nbr for messages
                orderNbr = order.OrderCD;
                //set the next record to be processed to the current of the graph
                graph.Orders.Current = order;                    
                order.Status = "I";
                graph.Orders.Update(order);
                //then save the results, including the processed flag or condition
                graph.Save.Press();
            }
            //catch any errors that happen in the receipt graph and format the message here, you can
            // also write code to a log or record extension to fix the error
            catch(Exception e) {
                //set line error to true so will skip the process correct below
                lineError = true;
                //set globaError flag to true to get the global message
                globalError = true;
                //create a custom error message to post on the grid
                var message = "Error Processing Order: " + orderNbr + ": " + e.Message;
            }
            //create a process complete message and assign to the grid line
            var messageTwo = " Order number: " + orderNbr + " Was Processed.";
            if(!lineError)
                PXFilteredProcessing<RecOrder, OrderFilter>.SetInfo(listProcessOrder.IndexOf(order), messageTwo);
        }
        //add last create the global error message that displays at the top of the screen
        if(globalError)
            throw new PXOperationCompletedWithErrorException("At Least One  order not Processed.");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior for processing screens. It shows only processed records in the grid after processing and the end-user needs to click on the Cancel/Refresh button or refresh the whole page to get back to the full list. You should not change the normal behaviors of the processing screens.

You can compare your screen with `Process Export Scenario` SM207035
[image]

After processing, only the processed records are displayed in the grid which is the standard desired behavior.
[image]

Comment: To do otherwise I would strongly recommend not to make it a processing screen by substituting the PXProcessing/PXFilteredProcessing view for a PXSelect view.

Comment: Thanks sir for reply, But in some screen like "Email Pending Processing", "Process Orders" screen it is showing all record without click refresh. how are they doing?

Comment: Those screens are different from yours, they are using a different UI which is documented in the following link. Note that this UI could be even more limiting and you can't customize it as easily.
https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2019/12/switch-between-old-and-new-processing-result-ui.html

Comment: On page 17 of this document, there is additional information on the Processing dialog box: https://adn.acumatica.com/content/uploads/2019/04/2019-R1-Developer-Release-Notes.pdf

Comment: Page 17 suggest to hide Processing box etc., I saw "Email Pending Processing", "Process Orders" screen, Both are using Processing page concept and showing the dialog box also, May you suggest way of implementation as Acumatica did in those screens?

Comment: As I mentioned this is not easy to customize and requires a lot of work to achieve, I can't suggest a solution in comment. It is also lacking documentation as it is a new feature.

Comment: Thanks, My processing dialog box is not showing verticalscroll bar to show all process records on processed Grid and paging is also disabled, but when i click on refresh then it started showing paging option to see processed record in dialoag box,May you know why is this occurred?

Comment: I think that might be a UI bug in the JavaScript layer if the scrollbar appear when the window is resized.

Comment: On resize grid doesn't fixed, But when i press F12 for inspect then grid automatically show paging and records goes to 2nd page. Also i saw there is overflow inline css, It hide vertical scroll, and horizontal scroll: auto.

Comment: Resize window, not grid.

Comment: Yes, On resize window it work. but its not a solution, May you suggest any trick to solve the issue?

Comment: Maybe change browser. It's a common issue in all Acumatica grids.

Comment: Besides that you would need to fill a bug report, it's a bug in Acumatica Framework in JavaScript event handlers.